# Update entity (JPA+MySQL) - Duplicate entry '142' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

In my project I need to update entity in database (MySQL). So my code looks like:

DAO:

```
public void updatepracownik (Pracownik pracus) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("baza");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();

    Pracownik pp= (Pracownik)em.find(Pracownik.class ,1);

    Query querys = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE  pracownik p SET p.idpracownik=?, p.imie=?, p.nazwisko=?, p.stanowisko=?, p.iloscGodzin=?  WHERE p.idpracownik=idpracownik");
    querys.setParameter(1, pracus.getIdpracownik());
    querys.setParameter(2, pracus.getImie());
    querys.setParameter(3, pracus.getNazwisko());
    querys.setParameter(4, pracus.getStanowisko());
    querys.setParameter(5, pracus.getiloscGodzin());
    querys.executeUpdate();

    em.persist(pracus);
    et.commit();
}
```

My Controller is:

```
@Override
@Transactional
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int idpracownik= Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("idpracownik"));
    String imie = req.getParameter("imie");
    String nazwisko = req.getParameter("nazwisko");
    String stanowisko = req.getParameter("stanowisko");
    double iloscGodzin = Double.valueOf(req.getParameter("iloscGodzin"));

    System.out.println(idpracownik);
    Pracownik pracus= new Pracownik (idpracownik, imie,  nazwisko,  stanowisko, iloscGodzin);

    Dao dao = new Dao();
    dao.updatepracownik(pracus);

    req.getRequestDispatcher("html/blank.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

and finally when I want to do update i get error message from MySQL:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '142' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: UPDATE pracownik p SET p.idpracownik=?, p.imie=?, p.nazwisko=?, p.stanowisko=?, p.iloscGodzin=?  WHERE p.idpracownik=idpracownik
bind => [5 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="UPDATE pracownik p SET p.idpracownik=?, p.imie=?, p.nazwisko=?, p.stanowisko=?, p.iloscGodzin=?  WHERE p.idpracownik=idpracownik")
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
```

I have to add - in my database table "idpracownik" is set as AI and Primary key. I am aware that i can't "update" PK but when i remove code (after word SET):

`p.idpracownik=?`
from 
`UPDATE  pracownik p SET p.idpracownik=?`

i get new entity with duplicated fields but with new (incremented) idpracownik.....
I'm stuck in this.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key should be used in the `where` clause to identify the particular record to be updated:

```
  Query querys = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE  pracownik p SET p.imie=?, p.nazwisko=?, p.stanowisko=?, p.iloscGodzin=?  WHERE p.idpracownik=?");



    querys.setParameter(5, pracus.getIdpracownik());
    querys.setParameter(1, pracus.getImie());
    querys.setParameter(2, pracus.getNazwisko());
    querys.setParameter(3, pracus.getStanowisko());
    querys.setParameter(4, pracus.getiloscGodzin());
```

Update:

You get a new record inserted because you create a new `Pracownik` instance and you persists it. You should get an existing instance based on whatever your id is. You seem to be mixing up raw database operations with whatever services your entity manager offers.

Comment: It's not working. I've changed the code like you wrote and now when i edit i get duplicated row with other id: 146  Ernest  Pajak  Manager  0.0  
147  Ernest  Nowak  Manager  0.0

Comment: If you get a duplicated row with another id, then your code executes an insert somewhere else. Update cannot create new records in the database.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've created new DAO class which has only 1 method (update query) and it's still the same result (duplicated rows). I check "idpracownik" in update method (by System.out.println) and the value is the same as the edited etnity so i'm sure i'm editing the row i want to.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure. You create a new entity and then persist it - this results in an insert operation.

Comment: I love You <3. I was figouring out that in the night so i've mixed up my update and create methods. You are great, now it works fine.